# Sending Email with Attachment that accepts particular file type in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

Now i fixed the filtering of file extension but i have a problem on "catch" it doesn't display any error message but good, it is not sending the email with wrong file type.

but my problem is here:
catch(Exception err)
            {

```
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblFile.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblStatus.Text = "There was an error occured while submitting your application";
            lblFile.Text = " Accepts .doc, .docx and .pdf files only!";
            return ;



protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (fileUpload1.HasFile) 
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        try
            {
                string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if (strExtension == ".docx" || strExtension == ".doc" || strExtension == ".pdf") 
                {

                    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
                    myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@yahoo.com"));
                    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("me@gmail.com");
                    myMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                    myMessage.Body = "<html><body><br/><b>Sender Name:</b>&nbsp;" + txtName.Text.ToString() + "<br/><br/><b>Email:</b>&nbsp;" + txtEmail.Text.ToString() +
                                     "<br/><br/><b>Contact Number:</b>&nbsp;" + txtContact.Text.ToString() + "<br/><br/><b>Subject</b>&nbsp;" + txtSubject.Text.ToString() +
                                     "<br/><br/><b>CV Summary:</b><br/><br/>" + txtSummary.Text.ToString() + "</body></html>";
                    myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    myMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName));


                    SmtpClient mySmtp = new SmtpClient();
                    mySmtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    mySmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "mypassword");
                    mySmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    mySmtp.Send(myMessage);

                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblStatus.Text = "We will contact you once you have been shortlisted to the position you are applying for. <br/> You may now close this window.";
                    txtName.Text = "";
                    txtEmail.Text = "";
                    txtSubject.Text = "";
                    txtSummary.Text = "";
                    txtContact.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblFile.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblStatus.Text = "There was an error occured while submitting your application";
                lblFile.Text = " Accepts .doc, .docx and .pdf files only!";
                return ;
            }
        }


}

protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtEmail.Text = "";
    txtSubject.Text = "";
    txtSummary.Text = "";
    txtContact.Text = "";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nicer way to do it:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileUpload1.HasFile) ;
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                try
                {
                    string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    if (strExtension != ".docx" || strExtension != ".doc" || strExtension != ".pdf")
                    {
                        lblFile.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblFile.Text = "You can attach .doc,.docx and pdf files only";
                        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblStatus.Text = "There was an error occured while sending your email. Please try again later.";
                        return;
                    }

                    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
                    myMessage.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                    myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("EMAIL@yahoo.com"));
                    myMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                    myMessage.Body = "<html><body><br/><b>Sender Name:</b>&nbsp;" + txtName.Text.ToString() + "<br/><br/><b>Email:</b>&nbsp;" + txtEmail.Text.ToString() +
                                    "<br/><br/><b>Contact Number:</b>&nbsp;" + txtContact.Text.ToString() + "<br/><br/><b>Subject</b>&nbsp;" + txtSubject.Text.ToString() +
                                    "<br/><br/><b>CV Summary:</b><br/><br/>" + txtSummary.Text.ToString() + "</body></html>";
                    myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    myMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName));


                    SmtpClient mySmtp = new SmtpClient();
                    mySmtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    mySmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EMAIL@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
                    mySmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    mySmtp.Send(myMessage);

                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Email successfully sent! We will contact you as soon as you have been shortlisted for the position you are applying for.<br/> Thank You. You can close this window now. ";
                    txtName.Text = "";
                    txtEmail.Text = "";
                    txtSubject.Text = "";
                    txtSummary.Text = "";
                    txtContact.Text = "";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }
```

Basically, you only want to catch exceptions i.e. IO or mail sending failures.

This code will return if the extension is not a doc, docx or pdf and not call the send mail code.

**Also, the myMessage.From() address must be a valid email address and the one that you supplied via your NetworkCredentials()**

Here is a cut down version of the code that I have tested and verified that it is working:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile) ;
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    try
                    {
                        string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        if (strExtension != ".docx" || strExtension != ".doc" || strExtension != ".pdf")
                        {
                            lblFile.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            lblFile.Text = "You can attach .doc,.docx and pdf files only";
                            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            lblStatus.Text = "There was an error occured while sending your email. Please try again later.";
                            return;
                        }

                        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
                        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("OtherPersonsEmail@email.xyz"));
                        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("YourEmailAddress@gmail.com");
                        myMessage.Subject = "Test";
                        myMessage.Body = "asd asd as d";
                        myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        myMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName));


                        SmtpClient mySmtp = new SmtpClient();
                        mySmtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        mySmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YourEmailAddress@gmail.com", "YourPassword");
                        mySmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        mySmtp.Send(myMessage);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: great! thank you so much. I'll try to try this and will get back to you asap. :)

Comment: its not working.. the email still not sending if the files was .doc or.pdf

Comment: I see your problem now. I notice that you are passing in the "From" mail message property. That must match your new System.Net.NetworkCredential() email address. i.e. your GMail account. You cannot send emails from anyone else's account.

Comment: still not working, after submitting the form it return on an error that the email was not send even the document meets the criteria.

Comment: i received also an error "unreachable code detected" on line mailmessage mymessage

Comment: I have tested it with my own Gmail address and password and sent it to another email account I have and it works. Have you verified that you are using the correct email address and password in the NetworkCredential property?

Comment: It is unreachable because it will not send if the attachment is not a PDF, DOC or DOCX. SO it will only send if the attachment is a PDF, DOC or DOCX.

Comment: ok it seems working now when i try to condition if the file extension meets the criteria otherwise it will return an error, but the error seems not displaying on catch.

Comment: i've edit your code, can you check it. sorry i was unable to answer my questions yet.

Comment: In the catch block set lblStatus.Text = ex.Message; and you will get the error message on the screen.

Comment: @Dhenn: This is a _question_ and _answer_ site -- do not edit someone else's post to try to reply to them. Do not post an answer except to _answer_ the question. Instead, **edit** your original question with any new content. Thanks.

Comment: catch(Exception err)
                {

                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblFile.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblStatus.Text = err.Message;
                    lblFile.Text = " Accepts .doc, .docx and .pdf files only!";
                }

Comment: @DhennMark I have modified the second code snippet. Let me know how you get on and please don't forget to mark as answer/upvote if you are satisfied that this works.